# How to create Window Form inside another one?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I need to embedded window form inside another one like this
[image]

Comment: You would want to look at `MDI` and pay attention to the `Parent` Property as well lots of examples on the web as well as here on Stackoverflow also are you wanting to do something like what `Excel` is already doing..? if so look at `Interop` and `Datagridview` of `GridView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to look up MDI (Multiple Document Interface).

Answer (score 2):

The following might do what you want. `ChildForm` is the form that you want to place inside of `ParentForm`.

```
ChildForm.TopLevel = false;
ParentForm.Controls.Add(ChildForm);
ChildForm.Show();
```

Note that you might have to play with the `Location` of the child form.